# force download .zip folder using php?

Tags: php

I'm, trying to force download dynamic files using php.

however, the files that get downloaded are empty and it shows as 0 bytes for some reason.

I get the files name correctly and i get the force download correctly but when i download the .zip folder, it is empty and it shows as 0 bytes.

could someone please let me know whats missing from my code?

here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  //echo 'correct';

  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $file = $id.'_myfiles.zip';


  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
  header("Content-type: application/zip");
  readfile("../upload/$file.zip");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $file.zip is in your path and you specify _myfiles.zip earlier. This results in _myfiles.zip.zip which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: @SvenSchneider, are you referring to the name of the folder? if so, I get the name of the folder correctly. example: `100_myfiles.zip`. but it is empty. 100 represents the $id by the way.

Comment: I meant the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: @SvenSchneider, nice one. sorry, i was a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = $id.'_myfiles.zip'; // == "104_myFiles.zip" for example.
```

So change:

```
 readfile("../upload/$file.zip");
```

To:

```
 readfile("../upload/$file");
```

Comment: nice one. I can't believe i was missing that.